# How can I add another Operating System onto NOOBS?

Tags: operating-systems, noobs

When NOOBS is booted up, there is a choice of a variety of Operating Systems.

Is it possible for me to add another Operating System onto this list (for example **MinePeon**)?
If so, how do I do it?

Additional Notes:
I am using a Raspberry Pi B with NOOBS 1.4.

Comment: Is it really necessary? Can't you distribute it simply as an Image since it would obviously be easier for everyone (even noobs ;-) ) to simply write an image based distribution to an SD card using Win 32 Disk Imager or something similar

Comment: Convert RetroPie SD Card Image to NOOBS Image https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Convert-RetroPie-SD-Card-Image-to-NOOBS-Image/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible (since NOOBS 1.3). To do so, plug in a physical keyboard and hold *shift* during boot. You should see the NOOBS GUI and should be able to select an OS to install (ie Raspbian). Let this OS install, once finished and it boots to Raspbian, set it up, then reboot. Hold *shift* again, select the secondary OS and click *install*. It should ask you if you want to overwrite or just install alongside. If this sounds too complicated or doesn't work, use BerryBoot.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make this clearer (now edited), I was meaning a separate Operating System that wasn't included in NOOBS. (An example being MinePeon). Thanks though :)

Comment: Oh right, im not sure in noobs but ik it can be done in berryboot

Comment: using Noobs 1.4 it only gives me the option to overwrite - not install alongside

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add operating systems in Noobs. Check out this link for further info,
https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs#how-to-create-a-custom-os-version

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Generally, link only answers are discouraged here, since they're subject to link rot. Please expand your answer to include at least a high level summary of its content.  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer