# how to install several different Operating Systems on pi 3 b+ sd card and how to access them

Tags: sd-card, kodi, pi-3b+, osmc

I wish to install several different Op Systems on one micro sd card for a pi 3b+.
I use octopi for running a 3d printer and interested in dietpi and more to experiment with. Will be looking into an entertainment/media system also.

Comment: research `RPi multiboot` ..... or buy two more SD cards

Answer (score 2):

[BerryBoot](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) lets you do this with supposedly any OS, unlike NOOBS (as per [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29328/how-can-i-add-another-operating-system-onto-noobs)).

Just make sure your SD card is large enough for each OS.

Comment: BerryBoot REQUIRES all OS to share kernel - so is fraught with difficulties.

Comment: @Milliways Do you have more info, or a link?

Answer (score 1):

[Pinn](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinn/) allows you to install [several OSes](https://pinn.mjh.nz/list/). I personally prefer [Berryboot](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) though (as suggested by Patrick Cook), because I think it's a bit more userfriendly. [This article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/noobs-vs-berryboot-installing-raspberry-pi/) compares them.